# Group SQL rows by column value without flattening

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table structure:

```
contact_block_key   contact_tab_key     contact_tab_order
==========================================================
test                overview            1
test1               overview            2
test3                                   0
test4                                   0
test5               personal            2
test6               personal            1
test7               family              3
test8               family              1
test9               family              2
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to select and group rows by `contact_tab_key` and be able to sort by `contact_tab_order`. I've been largely unable to do this. I tried using:

```
"select * from table group by contact_tab_key order by contact_tab_order";
```

but `group by` seems to reduce the row to one.

I also tried:

```
"select * from table order by contact_tab_key,contact_tab_order";
```

But this seems to order `contact_tab_key` alphanumerically, then by `contact_tab_order`. I want the order `overview` => `personal` => `family` to remain in tact.

Is there a way to preserve the row count and row order but give me groupings based on `contact_tab` that I can then sort by `contact_tab_order`? I've been doing this manually with PHP, but figured there's probably a better way to do it in SQL.

The desired output (skipping *null* `contact_tab_key`):

```
Array
(
    [overview] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => test1
        )

    [personal] => Array
        (
            [0] => test6
            [1] => test5
        )

    [family] => Array
        (
            [0] => test8
            [1] => test9
            [2] => test7
        )
)
```

Comment: If you want to keep the number of rows you can't group, then you must order them by `contact_tab_key` and then by `contact_tab_order`

Comment: I tried doing `order by contact_tab_key,contact_tab_order` but this sorts alphanumerically on the `contact_tab_key`, so when the next thing after `personal` comes, which is `family`, that gets sorted to the top. I'd prefer to keep `overview` => `personal` => `family`. Can SQL achieve this? Or shall I do this with PHP, where I don't sort by anything, I create an array of objects then sort those arrays independently.

Comment: That's exactly what you wrote in the question, saying it again doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "preserve the row order"? Rows in the database don't have any order to preserve. They don't remember the order they were added. If you want output in any specific order, you have to use `ORDER BY`.